# SharePoint 2010/2007 - Possible to change site definition for existing site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

We have started our effort to migrate to 2010 from 2007 SharePoint.

In 2007 we used a site definition.  After the migration, it is obvious we have work to do on our 2007 site definition.

1.) What is the best path for us?
2.) Can we create a new Site Definition in 2010 and change the site definition that existing sites used to the new one?

thx

Answer (score 0):

After you do the migration, you can export the site definition of a migrated site as a template and use it as your site template for new sites.

To change the definition of existing sites, you need to write code that loops through the sites and updates them. If you have very few you could do it manually.

Comment: That would be site templates and not site definitions. I think he means modifying/working with onet.xml